# Scale the size of a div based upon the position of the browser scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lightbox

I need to dynamically resize a div based upon the positon of the browser scroll bar. The desired behavior is to have the featured div of a lightbox be rendered at 800px wide when it is opened, but then scale down to 1/3 that size as you scroll down the page, and then continually increase in size as you scroll back up. So far I've been able to get it to scale up as I scroll down, but am unable to get it to scale down. If anyone can help me out with this, it would be very much appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/juicesandmilks/CnuAL/3/

-Michael

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/6APeM/1/

You have to remove the script tags if you put your js in the javascript part of jsFiddle.

Comment: ooo, thx for the heads up on the script tags PitaJ, however, the current implementation of the code makes the box bigger as you scroll down and smaller as you scroll up. I need to reverse that behavior so that the box becomes smaller as you scroll down.

Comment: Hi @PitaJ , I went to this link: http://jsfiddle.net/6APeM/1/
but the the functionality is still the same (scrolling down makes the div larger instead of smaller). Is that not the right link?

Comment: Hey @PitaJ, that's amazing! Thank you so much!

If you don't mind, could you please explain a little bit about how you canged the variable value? with this:

`
$(window).scroll(function () { 
      var a = 6;
      var percent =  100 - $(document).scrollTop() / (100 / a); // you can make it change size 
                                                         // faster by making var 'a' larger
      $("#lightbox-panel-1, #lightbox-panel-2, #lightbox-panel-3, #lightbox-panel-4").css("width", percent + '%'); 
    });
`

I'm trying to pick up .JS but it's been very difficult for me.

Comment: @MichaelLowell - I simply made it so it subtracts the scrolling from the width of the box. This way the width gets smaller as you scroll more.